# Converting a sparse matrix into cell array efficiently

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have this sparse matrix of the following form

Lets take an example of 5x10 matrix

```
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
 1    1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
 2    0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
 3    .............................
 4    .............................
 5    .............................
```

From this sparse matrix, I want to create a cell array C of form

```
C{1} 1
C{2} = [1,2]
...........
...........
...........
```

My sparse matrix is high dimensional like 40000 by 790000. How can I do it efficiently in matlab. I can definitely use a loop and do it inefficiently. But I want the most efficient. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the indices and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to group them by columns:

```
[ii, jj] = find(A);
C = accumarray(jj, ii, [], @(v) {v.'});
```

**Benchmarking**

```
%// Random sparse matrix. Code adapted from @teng's answer
sz = [4e4 79e4];
nz = 1e5; %// number of nonzeros
A = sparse(randi(sz(1),[nz 1]),randi(sz(2),[nz 1]),1,sz(1),sz(2));

tic;    
[ii, jj] = find(A);
C = accumarray(jj, ii, [], @(v) {v.'});
toc
```

Results:

- For `nz = 1e4`:

  ```
  Elapsed time is 0.099657 seconds.
  ```
- For `nz = 1e5`:

  ```
  Elapsed time is 0.756234 seconds.
  ```
- For `nz = 1e6`:

  ```
  Elapsed time is 5.431427 seconds.
  ```

Comment: not only does your 2-liner use less memory, your 2-liner is about 15 times faster than my 3-liner. :D Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

Let me get the party started...
let's start with the basics:

```
 tic;
 sz = [ 400 7900]; % hehe...
 aMat = sparse(randi(sz(1),[1000 1]),randi(sz(2),[1000 1]),1,sz(1),sz(2));
 aCell = mat2cell(aMat,ones([sz(1) 1]));
 preC = cellfun(@(x) x(x~=0), aCell,'UniformOutput',false);
 C = cellfun(@(x) find(x), preC,'UniformOutput',false);
 toc
```